# ImportError: No module named. Worker failed to boot

Tags: django, gunicorn

I am trying to get gunicorn working with my Nginx but it just can't seem to see the WSGI.py file.

I tried different combinations of my project name and with different paths.

This is how my wsgi.py file looks like:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'voopglobal.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

It should ideally say "Booting worker with PID and a PID number" but it gives me an error instead.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-61:~/voop-global-it-project/voopglobal$ gunicorn voopglobal.wsgi
[2019-09-10 12:01:01 +0000] [27716] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2019-09-10 12:01:01 +0000] [27716] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (27716)
[2019-09-10 12:01:01 +0000] [27716] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-09-10 12:01:01 +0000] [27720] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27720
[2019-09-10 12:01:01 +0000] [27720] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 377, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/voop-global-it-project/voopglobal/voopglobal/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[2019-09-10 12:01:01 +0000] [27720] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 27720)
[2019-09-10 12:01:02 +0000] [27716] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-09-10 12:01:02 +0000] [27716] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Django, Python3 and pip3 are installed.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-61:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-61:~$ django-admin --version
2.2.5
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-61:~$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the django version? can you post your gunicorn settings?

Comment: The problem is not in finding your wsgi file. It's in finding *Django*. Did you install it? Did you activate your virtualenv?

Comment: Is Django installed?

Comment: @NalinDobhal
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8

$ django-admin --version
2.2.5

$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: I am not using venv so I guess there is no point in making sure if I've activated it or not.

Comment: You are using django 2.2.5 which requires python 3, but from the traceback, it looks like it is pointing to python v2.7. You need to fix that.